# Animate Scroll Flex div to right from left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

On click of a panel (say `panel1`) I am trying to animate scroll to the newly added panel (`panel2`) to left side of the screen.
I have tried

```
windows.location = '#p2' // panel2 id
```

but that doesn't animate and bluntly takes the focus to the new panel

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jjpatel361/wtfc8o2t/3/) .

**Note**: I am not sure jquery or CSS animations can be done here.
looking for CSS animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
function addPanel(elemId) {
  $('#'+elemId).css('display', 'flex');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollLeft: $('#'+elemId).offset().left
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wtfc8o2t/14/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to animate your container so the new panel (`panel2`) is visible in the view port.

https://jsfiddle.net/wtfc8o2t/6/

```
function addPanel(elemId) {
  document.getElementById(elemId).style.display = 'flex';
  $( "#flex-container" ).animate({
    left: "-=450"
  }, 1000, function() {
    // Animation complete.
  });
}
```